# How to create horizontal progress bar with different segment color in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I want to create custom round corner horizontal progress bar with different color segment and then I want to list the separated color segment below the horizontal progress bar

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code in the question.

Comment: @feedMe i don't have idea to write code.. Please suggest me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask